# directed graph representation of LF

Tags: logic, formal-semantics, logical-form

I am a logician new to linguistics. I am curious if there has been any work on using the formalism of directed graphs (as opposed to, say, lambda-calculus or first-order logic) to represent LF of natural languages. I am proposing this because, in the philosophy literature, it appears that theorists have been struggling to account for the fact that "Romeo loves Juliet" and "Juliet loves Romeo" express two different propositions, but "1=2" and "2=1" express the same propositions. One intuitive thought I had is that this could be solved by representing relations as edges with directionality (as opposed to encoding their symmetricity/asymmetricity using the order of appearances of relata). But this might just be my ignorance of what LF is supposed to accomplish...

Comment: This turns out not to be such a problem for linguistics, whatever theorists are struggling with. Generally there's a distinction made between propositions with noun phrases and predicates like _love_, and equations like 1=2, even by linguists. Word order, however, is a given in real language, since simultaneity is impossible, and it can be used in a number of ways.

Comment: @jlawler thanks. Just a quick follow-up question: is the distinction between relations (including symmetrical relations, like "is married to" or "equals to") and equation, or is it between symmetrical and asymmetrical relations?

Comment: Both kinds occur. There is such a large number of lexical verbs and other predicates, though, that most attention is paid to them. Symmetric verbs like _marry_ are rare and relatively insignificant; almost everything hinges on number of arguments (0-3) and transitivity systems, so it's pretty asymmetrical. Asymmetry is information, after all.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. See [Arc pair grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_pair_grammar)....

Comment: Thanks! I have never heard of Arc pair grammar and will look it up.